# Jenkins + Gradle + Artifacts: Deploy only work once

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I'm using Gradle and Jenkins and want to deploy artifacts to Artifactory. Unfortunately this deployment works only once, when I start the build in Jenkins.

If I delete the workspace and the ~/.gradle Folder on the Jenkins server the deployment works again. Deleting only the workspace alone is not enough.

Seems like a bug for me. Do I have any unknown version conflicts. Or is it something different I don't see. Thanks for any help.

Environment:

- Jenkins 2.7.3
- Gradle 3.1
- Artifactory 4.13.0
- Jenkins Artifactory Plugin 2.7.2

**Gradle Build Script:** (Based on example from jfrog)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '4.4.5')
  }
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  group = 'org.jfrog.example.gradle'
  version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  status = 'integration'
}

artifactory {
  publish {
    defaults {
        publishConfigs('archives')
    }
  }
}

// Setting this property to true will make the artifactoryPublish task
// skip this module (in our case, the root module):
artifactoryPublish.skip = true
```

**Jenkins Artifactory Plugin Settings:**

- [x] Gradle-Artifactory-Integration
- [x] Capture and publish build info
- [x] Publish artifacts to Artifactory
- [x] Publish Maven Descriptors
- [x] Use Maven compatible Patterns

Rest is deactivated (not set).

**Log in Jenkins (Console Output)**, on second run with changed version and changed source code:

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.7.2
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[CdExampleArtifactory] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\gradle-3.1\bin\gradle.bat"' --init-script c:/temp/init-artifactory8368571638486556211gradle artifactoryPublish && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
:artifactoryPublish
:api:artifactoryPublish
:services:artifactoryPublish
:shared:artifactoryPublish
:services:webservice:artifactoryPublish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.422 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It looks like the task don't start the build (jar, etc.) process.

Comment: are you running `gradle build` in your jenkins job somewhere?

Comment: yes, build runs as task. If I delete ~/.gradle then build will be called anyway if I set it as task or not. At the second run artifactoryPublish does nothing regardless if build is configured or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

I have to deactivate the gradle deamon on the jenkins server (via GRADLE_OPTS).

Comment: can you show how it's done exactly - it would be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest Gradle Artifactory Plugin version 4.4.7 solves the compatibility issue with Gradle 3.1.

Gradle build snippet:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '4.4.7')
  }
}
```

Note the version.